# Adventure / Mystery book with a cool old lady and her house with automated amusements

Tags: identification-request

I read this in the early 2000s, I think. It was a paperback, with the main characters being a set of kids, at least three of them, with both boys and girls in the group. I don't remember the main part of the narrative, but I remember it involved them having an adventure or solving a mystery. There is an older lady who had a cool house with a number of button-invoked amenities. At the end of the book, as the kids are waiting for their parents to pick them up, or drive them home, they push the button marked "Pool", expecting to play billiards, only to have the floor open up into a swimming pool, to which one of them comments that they don't have swimsuits with them.

Comment: Maddeningly, I have this intense memory of having found this series in a different search within the past week, but not having had time to note the discovery properly. My search history does not match this possible false memory...

Comment: Did it seem old? What was the target audience, apparently?

Comment: @stormblessed: my vague impression is that it was not old at the time of reading, and was stunned at a YA audience.

Comment: "Aimed" at a YA audience...

Comment: @SeanDuggan set phasers to stun and take aim!